# Problems reading from file

Tags: android, serialization, android-file

If program is starting first time, then there are no data in cache, so data must be downloaded from server (with asyncTask) and saved to file.

```
public static String filename = "channels.txt";

FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
try {
   fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   out.writeObject(ChannelManager.mInstance);
   out.close();
   fos.close();
}
```

Main idea is that I serialize object and write it to file for later usage.

Then I try to read it:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
ObjectInputStream in = null;
try {
   fis = openFileInput(filename);
   in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   mChannelManager = (ChannelManager) in.readObject();
   Log.e("mChannelManager", mChannelManager.getChannel_list().get(3) + "");
   in.close();
   fis.close();
 }
```

If I try read it after it was writen to file, it works fine, but if I close or kill app and try to read from file I get null pointer exception :/

I tried saving file name into shared preferences and use it, but still got null pointer exception (thought it's string/object/memory reference problem)

So where is (or might be) the problem?

Error Log:

```
10-07 10:54:15.773  10630-10647/? E/CMC->NioClient3﹕ NioClient thread get exception e: I/O exception while read message:
10-07 10:54:30.123  10741-10741/? E/APKInstallReceiver﹕ context = android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@41597d68, intent.getAction() = android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED, intent.getDataString() = package:com.iptviq.mobile.android.skynettv
10-07 10:54:31.393  12624-12624/com.iptviq.mobile.android.skynettv E/IN CACHE﹕ +
10-07 10:54:31.413  12624-12624/com.iptviq.mobile.android.skynettv E/Returning channel_list﹕ null
10-07 10:54:31.423  12624-12624/com.iptviq.mobile.android.skynettv E/AndroidRuntime﹕    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iptviq.mobile.android.skynettv/com.iptviq.mobile.android.engine.SkynetTvMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.iptviq.mobile.android.engine.SkynetTvMainActivity.onCreate(SkynetTvMainActivity.java:202)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit 2:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity = this;
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SERVER_IP = preferences.getString("serverIP", "192.168.37.14");
    SERVERPORT = preferences.getString("serverPort", "8221");
    areChannelsInCache = preferences.getBoolean("areChannelsInCache", false);
    filename = preferences.getString("fileName", filename);
    if (!areChannelsInCache) {
        Log.e("NOT IN CACHE", "+");
        mDownloadChannelsTask = new DownloadChannelsTask();
        mDownloadChannelsTask.execute();
    } else {
        Log.e("IN CACHE", "+");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(filename);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            mChannelManager = (ChannelManager) in.readObject();
            Log.e("mChannelManager", mChannelManager.getChannel_list().get(3) + "");
            in.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("mChannelManager", "error1 on reading " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e("mChannelManager", "error2 on reading " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

AsyncTask works fine (to download data). When it's done it calls handler that is saving to file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeObject(ChannelManager.mInstance);
    out.close();
    fos.close();
    Log.e("SAVED TO FILE", ":)");
    preferences.edit().putBoolean("areChannelsInCache", true).commit();
    preferences.edit().putString("fileName", filename).commit();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e("error @ main on saving data to file", ":(( " + ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: please post stack trace with Exception

Comment: Can you post all your `create` method?

Comment: updated with onCreate and saving to file code

Comment: Have you tried not using `MODE_APPEND`, use `MODE_PRIVATE` instead.

Comment: Post the code of `SkynetTvMainActivity.onCreate()` method.

Comment: Also you trying to read object from file on main thread which is very very bad...

Comment: at 202 line is: Log.e("mChannelManager", mChannelManager.getChannel_list().get(3) + ""); I think this is caused because reading from file was unsuccessful. May be file not found or something :?

Yes, I tried MODE_PRIVATE - same problem.
I already posted onCreate method

Comment: if I remove mChannelManager.getChannel_list().get(3) and leave only mChannelManager in Log it's working, but channel mannager is saving arrayList with channels so I need to get them :? So maybe it's problem in serialization. Why arrayList might be null?

Comment: found out that on serialization field can't be static, otherwise serialization will skip it. This solved me problem :) 

Thank you all for help and time

Answer (score 0):

Flush your output stream before closing

Comment: FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream has no flush method